# http.so loaded but http_get undefined

Tags: php, http, lamp

I have LAMP installed on my linux distribution:

///

PHP 5.4.9-4ubuntu2.4 (cli) (built: Dec 12 2013 04:29:20) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans

///

In order to use http_get from pecl_http php extension I have explicitly installed it and added the http.so extension to php.ini.

Now I am in the following scenario. Using the simple php code below:

```
echo var_dump(extension_loaded("http"));

echo var_dump(extension_loaded("raphf"));

echo var_dump(extension_loaded("propro"));

echo var_dump(function_exists("http_get"));

$response = http_get("www.google.com");

echo $response;
```

I got the following results:

///

```
boolean true

boolean true

boolean true

**boolean false**
```

I am not sure why extension_loaded("http") returns true but function_exists("http_get") returns false, so I cannot use the function http_get without getting the following in the Apache log file

"[Tue Dec 31 12:32:26 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function http_get() in /home/user/main.php on line 32"

Could you please help me troubleshooting this?

(same issue using the console interactive mode php -a)

phpinfo() shows:

///

http

HTTP Support    enabled
Extension Version   2.0.3

Used Library    Compiled    Linked
libz    1.2.7   1.2.7
libcurl 7.29.0  7.29.0
libevent    disabled    disabled

Directive   Local Value Master Value
http.etag.mode  crc32b  crc32b

///

Thanks

Comment: It looks that the extension is installed correctly. Do a <?php phpinfo(); ?> to see a more verbose output of the installed extensions.

Comment: hi Alex, added the output of phpinfo() related to html extension

Comment: Ah I just found something-- Apparently all the old `http_*()` functions were only present in v1 and not in v2. That's mentioned in one of the comments here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/http.install.php PECL HTTP 2 docs: http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks a lot, I think this replies to my question (after many hours spent).

Comment: The docs at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.http.php are not clear at all unfortunately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Michael Berkowski says, the 2.x branch is totally new and it works with a different API.

You can go with the 1.x branch and use the old functions this way:

```
pecl uninstal pecl_http
pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6
```

Then you can use http_get

Anyway, if this is a fresh new project, it is recommended to go with the newest API.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate slightly on Alex's answer, unless I missed something, the Php Manuel doesn't really reflect how this extension has changed.  And the link in the comment on your question doesn't seem to work anymore. I think what you want now, to get that same behavior, is [http\Client::send()](https://mdref.m6w6.name/http/Client/send).