# PHP http_get in new api

Tags: php, http

I am trying to do a simple GET request in PHP. In all examples I found it is done using http_get("http:/blahblah..."). I understand from [http.so loaded but http_get undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858492/http-so-loaded-but-http-get-undefined) that there is some new API which doesn't have http_get. This API also doesn't have any readable documentation or examples. Could somebody please explain how I can do a GET request using the new http API? Or maybe there is some other easier way?

Comment: What api are you speaking of? In PHP you use $_GET or $_REQUEST to access the variables sent through the url.

Comment: This API: http://devel-m6w6.rhcloud.com/mdref/http

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to use GET in PHP is to put it in a variable like so...

`$myVariable = $_GET['HTTP_URI'];`

Which will put the URL int he variable, for example `http://example.com`. Or you could do...

`$myVariable = $_GET['id'];`

Which will return `10` if you have the following URL...

`http://example.com/index.php?id=10`

Hopefully that's what your looking for after reading your question. Reply if it's not what your after and I'll have a rethink for you.

Comment: I am trying to do a get request from within the php file, and not access the GET variables. So, something like <?php $response = http_get("hxxp://request..."); function($response); ... ?>. Except that http_get doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after spending over an hour trying to decypher the HTTP api documentation I solved this by using curl. HTTP api is overcomplicated and lacks proper documentation. This makes it completely unusable and frustrating, especially for someone who is new to PHP.

This does what I want:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.myurl.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/php/examples/getpageinvar.html

Comment: You can use many things. `include()` with output buffer, `file_get_contents()`, `fopen()` and other methods.

Comment: curl might not work in some case, especially facing auth issue