# I'm trying to get pecl_http

Tags: php, http, pear, pecl

I installed the `pecl` package, but the `pecl_http` won't install.

Here is my `pecl` list:

```
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package        Version State
propro         1.0.0   stable
raphf          1.1.0   stable
uploadprogress 1.0.3.1 stable
```

I'm trying to get the `pecl_http` on the list but it is not working. 
What am I doing wrong?

I am working on Ubuntu. I installed `pecl_http`
with the following command:

```
sudo pecl install pecl_http
```

I have a `pecl_http-2.5.5.tgz` file and the files in the `.tgz` package are written in C.

I have also tried `sudo pecl install http`, without success. 
Can any one tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to give details of errors, etc to show what actually went wrong, rather than just saying 'it is not working'.

Answer (score 2):

Returning to pecl_http v1 helped me. I found the solution from the question [http.so loaded but http_get undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858492/http-so-loaded-but-http-get-undefined). Advancing to PHP 7 didn't seem practical due to the presumed avalanche of modifications needed to other software.

```
sudo pecl uninstall pecl_http
sudo pecl install pecl_http-1.7.6
```

Comment: i have tried that it did not work, it does not install the pecl-http.so file  , i also tried to compile the C source, it said some files were missing , i Solved the Problem though

Comment: I got it to work on PHP 5.5 by installing pecl_http-2.5.5.