# Php pecl_http loaded, but not defining any functions

Tags: php, http, module, php-extension, pecl

I'm attempting to use the `http_build_str()` and `http_build_url()` functions.  I've installed and enabled pecl_http already, but I still get this error:

```
Call to undefined function http_build_str()
```

I've verified up down and sideways that the extension is installed and enabled.  I've also already encountered the kind of warning messages that happen if their permissions are set wrong, so I can rule that out as well.

Then I came upon 
[extension_loaded()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php) and [get_extension_funcs()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-extension-funcs.php).  Their results are a little confounding:

```
print_r(extension_loaded('http')); // true
print_rt(get_extension_funcs('http')); // []
```

Doing a sanity-check, I ran those functions against a different extension that I know works, and I did get some results in the function array.  As you can clearly see, "http_build_str" and "http_build_url", are not part of `get_extension_funcs()`'s output as I would have expected.  Can anyone please help?

In case it matters, I'm setting this up in a Docker container, and what I *think* the relevant portions of its configuration are as follows:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    git-core \
    build-essential \
    openssl \
    libssl-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif zip pcntl ftp
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN pecl install propro raphf \
    && docker-php-ext-enable propro raphf \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pear
RUN pecl install pecl_http xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable http xdebug \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pear
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the Php Manuel is a little out of date on this one.
Don't know how I missed it, but this question is a duplicate of [http.so loaded but http_get undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858492/http-so-loaded-but-http-get-undefined).

The link in the comment answering this is dead, the official docs seem to have moved.
https://mdref.m6w6.name/http/QueryString

Seems the functionality is all still there, just in the form of a few classes now instead of functions.

```
$params = ['test1'=>'val1','test2'=>'val2'];
$queryHandler = new QueryString($params);
$queryString = (string)$queryHandler;
print_r($queryString); // test1=val1&test2=val2
```